# Problems with Omnifaces GzipResponseFilter and page redirect (Glassfish only)

Tags: jsf, redirect, glassfish-3, omnifaces

I get an error when I try to redirect a page in JSF action with a h:commandLink when I use the Omnifaces GzipResponseFilter (only in Glassfish).

Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current state = FLUSHED, new state = CODING_END

Environment
Glassfish 3
Omnifaces 1.7 (GzipResponseFilter)
Mojarra 2.1.27
JDK 6

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>gzipResponseFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>gzipResponseFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

MyBean.doAction()

```
Faces.redirect("anotherPage.jsf");
```

page.xhtml

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myBean.doAction()}">Click</h:commandLink>
```

The problem happens only in Glassfish, I tested in Tomcat and it works.
If I remove the GzipResponseFilter declaration, the redirect works normally on both servers.

Do you know if it's a bug on Omnifaces or in my code?
Thanks in advance.

Stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current state = FLUSHED, new state = CODING_END
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.throwIllegalStateException(CharsetEncoder.java:951)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:537)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushLeftoverChar(StreamEncoder.java:223)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:282)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:130)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:216)
    at org.omnifaces.io.ResettableBufferedWriter.close(ResettableBufferedWriter.java:98)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.close(PrintWriter.java:295)
    at org.omnifaces.servlet.HttpServletResponseOutputWrapper.close(HttpServletResponseOutputWrapper.java:149)
    at org.omnifaces.servlet.GzipHttpServletResponse.close(GzipHttpServletResponse.java:133)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:150)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
```

Comment: Which GF3 version exactly? Tried a newer one if available?

Comment: I'm using the 3.1.1 version.
I use this version because this is the environment of my customers. What do you think about this problem?

Comment: Is it better to open a issue about it on omnifaces project?

Answer (score 0):

We can't get solve the problem with the redirection, but the Faces.redirect() works correctly when I use a "h:commandLink" with f:ajax.
The Faces.redirect() fails when it is called on a regular "h:commandLink", init or preRender method.
I'll open an Omnifaces issue for discuss.